# Rhino Mocks: How to return conditional result from a mock object method

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks, anonymous-methods

I would like to do something like the following but can't seem to get the syntax for the Do method quite right.

```
var sqr = new _mocks.CreateRenderer<ShapeRenderer>();
Expect.Call(sqr.CanRender(null)).IgnoreArguments().Do(x =>x.GetType() == typeof(Square)).Repeat.Any();
```

So basically, I would like to set up the sqr.CanRender() method to return true if the input is of type Square and false otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
Expect.Call(sqr.CanRender(null)).IgnoreArguments()
    .Do((Func<Shape, bool>) delegate(Agent x){return x.GetType() == typeof(Square);})
    .Repeat.Any();
```

EDIT: The answer was correct in spirit bu the original syntax did not quite work.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't able to use .Net Framework 3.5 (required by [Cristian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313030/rhino-mocks-how-to-return-conditonal-result-from-a-mock-object-method/313080#313080)) and therefore don't have access to the [System.Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) delegates then you'll need to define your own delegate.

Add to the class member:

```
private delegate bool CanRenderDelegate(Shape shape)
```

The expectation becomes:

```
Expect.Call(sqr.CanRender(null))
    .IgnoreArguments()
    .Do((CanRenderDelegate) delegate(Agent x){return x.GetType() == typeof(Square);})
    .Repeat.Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Rhino Mocks 3.5 you can now do the following:

```
Expect.Call( sqr.CanRender( Arg<Shape>.Is.TypeOf<Square>() ).Repeat.Any();
```

Look at this [wiki article](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx) for more information.

Comment: That's pretty cool, didn't know about the Arg static class.  I assume it works with sqr.Expect(x=>...) syntax as well?